# why is my output duplicating, my lines are 3-5, present lines are other ones present

Tags: python

Two name-salary pairs are read from input and are passed as arguments for print_pay(). Define a function print_pay() that has two parameters and outputs the following all on one line:

the value of the first parameter
' earns '
the value of the second parameter
' dollars per year.'
print_pay() should not return any value.
Click here for example
Ex: If the input is:
Sumit
79500
Ezra
4800
then the output is:

Sumit earns 79500 dollars per year.
Ezra earns 4800 dollars per year.

```
''' Your code goes here '''
def print_pay(name, pay):
    print(employee_name1, 'earns',employee_pay1, 'dollars per year.')
    print(employee_name2, 'earns',employee_pay2, 'dollars per year.')

employee_name1 = input()
employee_pay1 = int(input())
employee_name2 = input()
employee_pay2 = int(input())

print_pay(employee_name1, employee_pay1)
print_pay(employee_name2, employee_pay2)
```

It out puts the correct statement but twice in a row.
EX.
Sumit earns 79500 dollars per year.
Ezra earns 4800 dollars per year.
Sumit earns 79500 dollars per year.
Ezra earns 4800 dollars per year.

Comment: If you call a function twice, its going to do everything in that function, twice

Comment: Your function does not use its parameters.

Comment: Your `print_pay` prints both employees, and completely ignores its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to do

```
def print_pay(name, pay):
    print(name, 'earns',pay, 'dollars per year.')

employee_name1 = input()
employee_pay1 = int(input())
employee_name2 = input()
employee_pay2 = int(input())

print_pay(employee_name1, employee_pay1)
print_pay(employee_name2, employee_pay2)
```